# Create table from lists containing numbers and words

Tags: python, list, matlab, for-loop, export-to-csv

I am creating a print output using a loop in this way:

```
new_coordinates = [[14.292429, 47.557149], [14.292429, 47.557149], [14.292429, 47.557149], [14.29902, 47.552474], [14.29902, 47.552474], [14.332263, 47.52663], [14.332263, 47.52663], [14.333375, 47.525116], [14.333375, 47.525116], [14.338493, 47.525643], [14.338493, 47.525643], [14.335595, 47.525614], [14.335595, 47.525614], [14.314937, 47.574178], [14.314937, 47.574178], [14.318924, 47.575619], [14.318924, 47.575619], [14.314233, 47.573812], [14.314233, 47.573812], [14.31484, 47.574285], [14.31484, 47.574285], [14.29902, 47.552474]]       
        
new_coords = zip(new_coordinates[0:], new_coordinates[1:])
        
        for c1, c2 in new_coords:
                
            body = {"coordinates":[c1, c2],"extra_info":["waycategory"]}
    
            headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Type': 'application/geo+json; charset=utf-8'
            }
            call = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ors/v2/directions/driving-hgv/geojson', json=body, headers=headers)
            weiter = call.text
            data = json.loads(weiter)
            
            Waycategory = data['features'][0]['properties']['extras']['waycategory']['summary']
        
            for wc in Waycategory:
                print(wc['value'])
            
            for wc in Waycategory:
                print(wc['amount'])
            
            Duration = data['features'][0]['properties']['summary']['duration']
        
            print(Duration)
        
        print('ArriveAtLocation')
```

The output looks like this:

```
0.0
100.0
471.0
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
1.0
0.0
82.65
12.44
4.92
872.6
3.0
100.0
195.8
1.0
3.0
99.75
0.25
14.4
0.0
100.0
25.9
1.0
3.0
99.69
0.31
20.4
3.0
100.0
334.8
1.0
3.0
99.78
0.22
31.6
0.0
1.0
99.43
0.57
27.8
3.0
1.0
0.0
92.82
6.05
1.13
1811.0
3.0
100.0
130.5
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
100.0
11266.9
ArriveAtLocation
0.0
3.0
99.76
0.24
151.7
ArriveAtLocation
0.0
3.0
99.96
0.04
150.1
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
100.0
8138.6
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
100.0
165.1
1.0
0.0
3.0
99.66
0.33
0.0
20.3
0.0
100.0
14.1
1.0
100.0
17.1
3.0
1.0
99.95
0.05
451.5
1.0
100.0
67.6
0.0
100.0
7.7
1.0
3.0
0.0
99.51
0.49
0.0
47.4
3.0
100.0
273.1
3.0
1.0
0.0
87.83
10.75
1.42
1075.6
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
1.0
100.0
0.0
3059.0
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
100.0
130.0
1.0
3.0
99.78
0.22
31.6
0.0
1.0
99.43
0.57
27.8
3.0
1.0
0.0
92.82
6.05
1.13
1811.0
3.0
100.0
89.3
1.0
3.0
99.89
0.11
75.1
ArriveAtLocation
0.0
100.0
502.2
ArriveAtLocation
0.0
100.0
471.0
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
1.0
0.0
82.65
12.44
4.92
872.6
3.0
100.0
195.8
1.0
3.0
99.75
0.25
14.4
0.0
100.0
25.9
1.0
3.0
99.69
0.31
20.4
3.0
100.0
334.8
1.0
3.0
99.78
0.22
31.6
0.0
1.0
99.43
0.57
27.8
3.0
1.0
0.0
92.82
6.05
1.13
1811.0
3.0
100.0
130.5
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
1.0
100.0
0.0
10622.2
ArriveAtLocation
1.0
3.0
99.91
0.09
88.0
ArriveAtLocation
3.0
100.0
85.1
ArriveAtLocation
1.0
3.0
99.89
0.11
36.4
ArriveAtLocation
0.0
1.0
100.0
0.0
358.9
ArriveAtLocation
```

​Now I need to get this in a shape, where it is actually usable e.g. in MatLab. I read that you can print to table from lists. So my guess is to print the above to separate lists and then export it to a table.

First step, create lists:

```
        value_list = []
        
        for wc in Waycategory:
            value_list.append(wc['value'])
        
        amount_list = []
        
        for wc in Waycategory:
            amount_list.append(wc['amount'])
        
        Duration = data['features'][0]['properties']['summary']['duration']
        
        duration_list = []
        
        duration_list.append(Duration)
        
        print(value_list)
        print(amount_list)
        print(duration_list)
    
    print('ArriveAtLocation')
```

to get:

```
[0.0]
[100.0]
[471.0]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[82.65, 12.44, 4.92]
[872.6]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[195.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[334.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.78, 0.22]
[31.6]
[0.0, 1.0]
[99.43, 0.57]
[27.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[92.82, 6.05, 1.13]
[1811.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[130.5]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[195.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[334.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.78, 0.22]
[31.6]
[0.0, 1.0]
[99.43, 0.57]
[27.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[92.82, 6.05, 1.13]
[1811.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[326.2]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[806.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[84.78, 14.34, 0.89]
[517.0]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[1.0]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.44, 0.56]
[38.5]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[495.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[130.5]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0]
[100.0]
[11266.9]
ArriveAtLocation
[0.0, 3.0]
[99.76, 0.24]
[151.7]
ArriveAtLocation
[0.0, 3.0]
[99.96, 0.04]
[150.1]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0]
[100.0]
[8138.6]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0]
[100.0]
[165.1]
[1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
[99.66, 0.33, 0.0]
[20.3]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[14.1]
[1.0]
[100.0]
[17.1]
[3.0, 1.0]
[99.95, 0.05]
[451.5]
[1.0]
[100.0]
[67.6]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[7.7]
[1.0, 3.0, 0.0]
[99.51, 0.49, 0.0]
[47.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[273.1]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[165.1]
[1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
[99.66, 0.33, 0.0]
[20.3]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[14.1]
[1.0]
[100.0]
[17.1]
[3.0, 1.0]
[99.95, 0.05]
[451.5]
[1.0]
[100.0]
[67.6]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[7.7]
[1.0, 3.0, 0.0]
[99.51, 0.49, 0.0]
[47.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[273.1]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[87.83, 10.75, 1.42]
[1075.6]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0, 1.0]
[100.0, 0.0]
[3059.0]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0]
[100.0]
[130.0]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.78, 0.22]
[31.6]
[0.0, 1.0]
[99.43, 0.57]
[27.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[92.82, 6.05, 1.13]
[1811.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[326.2]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[806.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[84.78, 14.34, 0.89]
[517.0]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[1.0]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.44, 0.56]
[38.5]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[495.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[89.3]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.89, 0.11]
[75.1]
ArriveAtLocation
[0.0]
[100.0]
[502.2]
ArriveAtLocation
[0.0]
[100.0]
[471.0]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[82.65, 12.44, 4.92]
[872.6]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[195.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[334.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.78, 0.22]
[31.6]
[0.0, 1.0]
[99.43, 0.57]
[27.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[92.82, 6.05, 1.13]
[1811.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[130.5]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[195.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[334.8]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.78, 0.22]
[31.6]
[0.0, 1.0]
[99.43, 0.57]
[27.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[92.82, 6.05, 1.13]
[1811.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[326.2]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.75, 0.25]
[14.4]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[25.9]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.69, 0.31]
[20.4]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[806.8]
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[84.78, 14.34, 0.89]
[517.0]
[0.0]
[100.0]
[1.0]
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.44, 0.56]
[38.5]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[495.0]
[3.0]
[100.0]
[130.5]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0, 1.0]
[100.0, 0.0]
[10622.2]
ArriveAtLocation
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.91, 0.09]
[88.0]
ArriveAtLocation
[3.0]
[100.0]
[85.1]
ArriveAtLocation
[1.0, 3.0]
[99.89, 0.11]
[36.4]
ArriveAtLocation
[0.0, 1.0]
[100.0, 0.0]
[358.9]
ArriveAtLocation
```

Notice that Duration represents the duration for all values - I am planning on changing them in Matlab according to their percentage. So what I'm thinking is that I need from here is the following output:

```
  Value Amount Duration
    0   100.00 471
    AaL AaL    AaL
    3    82.65 872.6
    1    12.44 872.6
    0     4.92 872.6
    3   100.00 195.8
    1    99.75  14.4
    3     0.25  14.4
```

I have no clue how to get there - splitting with `ArriveAtLocation` is an issue, but important to know when I'm arriving at a location. I hope this shows enough effort to where I am trying to go - can somebody please hint me a way to get there?

Comment: The code you've provided is in Python but you're repeatedly asking about MATLAB - if you want to use MATLAB then what have you tried in that language? Do you understand the basics of table manipulation in MATLAB? This question seems a bit too broad if not, because it's starting from "what is a table in MATLAB" and "I have some data" and resulting in a formatted data set...

Comment: the above code requests data, this step can not be done in MATLAB. I just need to get the requested data in a table in MATLAB. Sorry, if that could be understood in another way

Comment: You definitely can do post requests to get data within MATLAB... ignoring that, can you simplify your problem to make it *specific*? i.e. remove the unrelated bit about fetching the data, create a [mcve] where you have, for example, an ASCII (.txt) file which we could copy, then the MATLAB code you've tried to convert this to a table?